# How can I execute native queries in my Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a requirement to define composite foreign keys in my Model.Looks it is not supported currently. So, i try to run native queries in my model.

I have two tables(`vwAlarm, vwYfUserToSiteMappings`) Both has two columns.

> CompanyId,SiteCode

I want to return single row, by joining both columns from two tables.

Here is my Model;

```
class Alarm extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'vwAlarm';
    protected $primaryKey = 'AlarmId';

..

 public function Site()
    {
        $rec = \DB::table('vwAlarm')
            ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings', 'vwAlarm.SiteCode', '=', 'vwYfUserToSiteMappings.SiteCode')
            ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings','vwAlarm.CompanyId', '=', 'vwYfUserToSiteMappings.CompanyId')
            ->first();

        return $rec;
}
```

Im getting

```
 QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The objects "vwYfUserToSiteMappings" and "vwYfUserToSiteMappings" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them. (SQL: select top 1 * from [vwAlarm] inner join [vwYfUserToSiteMappings] on [vwAlarm].[SiteCode] = [vwYfUserToSiteMappings].[SiteCode] inner join [vwYfUserToSiteMappings] on [vwAlarm].[CompanyId] = [vwYfUserToSiteMappings].[CompanyId])
```

How can I correct my query?

Comment: If you have written Raw SQL Query somewhere. you can directly execute it using `DB:raw()`. Read More https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set alias name for table name like below

```
$rec = \DB::table('vwAlarm')
            ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings AS vw1', 'vwAlarm.SiteCode', '=', 'vw1.SiteCode')
            ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings AS vw2','vwAlarm.CompanyId', '=', 'vw2.CompanyId')
            ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks works . But the answer returns non relavant Site details. How can I return relavent Site entry for that Alarm model. I mean equivalent for  //$this->belongsTo//

Comment: I mean returned SIte details are wrong when compare with AlarmTables primaryKey(AlarmId)

Comment: first of all try to build native mysql query and run it in mysql database console and check that did you getting desired result or not .

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
 $rec = \DB::table('vwAlarm')
        ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings AS vwSiteCode', 'vwSiteCode.SiteCode', '=', 'vwAlarm.SiteCode')
        ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings AS vwCompanyId','vwCompanyId.CompanyId', '=', 'vwAlarm.CompanyId')
        ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks it works. . But the answer returns non relavant Site details. How can I return relavent Site entry for that Alarm model. I mean equivalent for //$this->belongsTo//

Comment: I mean returned SIte details are wrong when compare with AlarmTables primaryKey(AlarmId)

Comment: @Ratha Please give me more details

Comment: If you see my Alarm model, I have defined primaryKey as "AlarmId". I have two tables. vwAlarm and vwYfUserToSiteMappings, I'll pass AlarmId from My webform, I expect to return details belongs to that AlarmId. Some details are in vwAlarm table some are in vwYfUserToSiteMappings table. But both table have SiteCode,ComapnyId columns common. SO I try to join them

Comment: @Ratha: Ok let me check it